# Adding mean points to geom_boxplot with fun = mean or geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add mean points to my boxplots. I am using `fun = mean` which has worked for a previous graph. I think the problem is linked to there being two factors - present/absent and then fill being my "PredictedBehaviours".

Below is the code I have been trying and a sample of my data.

```
ggplot(proportionts, aes(x=w.wout, y= percentage, fill=PredictedBehaviour))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape= NA)+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=20, size=3, color="red", fill="red") +
  theme_classic () + my_scale + 
  theme( axis.text.y=  element_text( size = 16, angle =0)
```

Bellow is my data

```
    SharkID w.wout  PredictedBehaviour  count   percentage
1   3   Absent  Ascending   17  0.000134147
2   3   Absent  Burst   5   3.95E-05
3   3   Absent  Descending  3   2.37E-05
4   3   Absent  High.energy.swimming    15969   0.126011032
5   3   Absent  Low.energy.swimming 72781   0.574313288
6   3   Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  25241   0.199176182
7   3   Absent  Travel  12711   0.100302224
8   3   Present Burst   13  0.002442691
9   3   Present High.energy.swimming    2153    0.404547163
10  3   Present Low.energy.swimming 16  0.003006389
11  3   Present Medium.energy.swimming  3131    0.588312664
12  3   Present Travel  9   0.001691094
13  4   Absent  Ascending   225 0.002994968
14  4   Absent  Burst   6   7.99E-05
15  4   Absent  Descending  304 0.004046535
16  4   Absent  High.energy.swimming    9169    0.122048292
17  4   Absent  Low.energy.swimming 60392   0.803876155
18  4   Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  2051    0.027300801
19  4   Absent  Travel  2979    0.039653382
20  4   Present Ascending   62  0.001539111
21  4   Present Descending  346 0.008589231
22  4   Present High.energy.swimming    5964    0.148052528
23  4   Present Low.energy.swimming 30719   0.762579748
24  4   Present Medium.energy.swimming  243 0.006032321
25  4   Present Travel  2949    0.07320706
26  5   Absent  Ascending   59  0.000577582
27  5   Absent  Descending  77  0.000753793
28  5   Absent  High.energy.swimming    1637    0.016025453
29  5   Absent  Low.energy.swimming 98233   0.96165443
30  5   Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  349 0.003416544
31  5   Absent  Travel  1795    0.017572198
32  5   Present Ascending   35  0.002265372
33  5   Present Burst   15  0.000970874
34  5   Present Descending  63  0.00407767
35  5   Present High.energy.swimming    5667    0.366796117
36  5   Present Low.energy.swimming 7839    0.507378641
37  5   Present Medium.energy.swimming  1655    0.107119741
38  5   Present Travel  176 0.011391586
39  6   Absent  Ascending   15  0.000145017
40  6   Absent  Burst   19  0.000183688
41  6   Absent  Descending  38  0.000367377
42  6   Absent  High.energy.swimming    3690    0.035674233
43  6   Absent  Low.energy.swimming 63573   0.614611934
44  6   Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  671 0.006487103
45  6   Absent  Travel  35430   0.342530647
46  6   Present Ascending   9   0.000733915
47  6   Present Burst   3   0.000244638
48  6   Present Descending  293 0.023893011
49  6   Present High.energy.swimming    7376    0.601484139
50  6   Present Low.energy.swimming 2912    0.237462285
51  6   Present Medium.energy.swimming  1042    0.084971051
52  6   Present Travel  628 0.05121096
53  7   Absent  High.energy.swimming    31765   0.624312107
54  7   Absent  Low.energy.swimming 10733   0.210947327
55  7   Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  7849    0.154264937
56  7   Absent  Travel  533 0.010475629
57  7   Present Burst   102 0.00354499
58  7   Present High.energy.swimming    21955   0.763041741
59  7   Present Low.energy.swimming 142 0.004935182
60  7   Present Medium.energy.swimming  6574    0.228478087
61  8   Absent  Ascending   729 0.002603227
62  8   Absent  Burst   70  0.000249967
63  8   Absent  Descending  966 0.003449544
64  8   Absent  High.energy.swimming    187764  0.670497113
65  8   Absent  Low.energy.swimming 51724   0.184704164
66  8   Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  13097   0.04676882
67  8   Absent  Travel  25687   0.091727165
68  8   Present Ascending   803 0.029815832
69  8   Present Burst   7   0.000259914
70  8   Present Descending  143 0.005309669
71  8   Present High.energy.swimming    18200   0.675776029
72  8   Present Low.energy.swimming 4888    0.181494133
73  8   Present Medium.energy.swimming  631 0.023429378
74  8   Present Travel  2260    0.083915045
75  9   Absent  Ascending   5029    0.065226978
76  9   Absent  Burst   32  0.000415045
77  9   Absent  Descending  2988    0.038754864
78  9   Absent  High.energy.swimming    5821    0.075499351
79  9   Absent  Low.energy.swimming 38502   0.499377432
80  9   Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  268 0.003476005
81  9   Absent  Travel  24460   0.317250324
82  9   Present Ascending   410 0.045897235
83  9   Present Burst   9   0.0010075
84  9   Present Descending  545 0.061009739
85  9   Present High.energy.swimming    2466    0.276055077
86  9   Present Low.energy.swimming 3680    0.41195567
87  9   Present Medium.energy.swimming  25  0.002798612
88  9   Present Travel  1798    0.201276167
89  10  Absent  Ascending   595 0.014674329
90  10  Absent  Burst   3   7.40E-05
91  10  Absent  Descending  256 0.006313661
92  10  Absent  High.energy.swimming    777 0.019162947
93  10  Absent  Low.energy.swimming 32057   0.790613362
94  10  Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  26  0.000641231
95  10  Absent  Travel  6833    0.168520482
96  10  Present Ascending   149 0.049354091
97  10  Present Burst   4   0.001324942
98  10  Present Descending  6   0.001987413
99  10  Present High.energy.swimming    100 0.033123551
100 10  Present Low.energy.swimming 2739    0.907254058
101 10  Present Medium.energy.swimming  3   0.000993707
102 10  Present Travel  18  0.005962239
103 11  Absent  Ascending   34  0.000740741
104 11  Absent  Descending  1632    0.035555556
105 11  Absent  High.energy.swimming    6506    0.141742919
106 11  Absent  Low.energy.swimming 27867   0.607124183
107 11  Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  6038    0.131546841
108 11  Absent  Travel  3823    0.08328976
109 11  Present Ascending   85  0.005441741
110 11  Present Burst   37  0.002368758
111 11  Present Descending  234 0.014980794
112 11  Present High.energy.swimming    3665    0.234635083
113 11  Present Low.energy.swimming 8389    0.537067862
114 11  Present Medium.energy.swimming  1274    0.0815621
115 11  Present Travel  1936    0.123943662
116 12  Absent  Ascending   18  0.000363629
117 12  Absent  Descending  15  0.000303024
118 12  Absent  High.energy.swimming    1102    0.022262177
119 12  Absent  Low.energy.swimming 47832   0.966283509
120 12  Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  64  0.001292903
121 12  Absent  Travel  470 0.009494758
122 12  Present Ascending   99  0.0042859
123 12  Present Burst   26  0.00112559
124 12  Present Descending  281 0.012165029
125 12  Present High.energy.swimming    9474    0.410147625
126 12  Present Low.energy.swimming 11216   0.485562146
127 12  Present Medium.energy.swimming  789 0.034157323
128 12  Present Travel  1214    0.052556388
129 13  Present Ascending   47  0.006329966
130 13  Present Descending  60  0.008080808
131 13  Present High.energy.swimming    1206    0.162424242
132 13  Present Low.energy.swimming 6079    0.818720539
133 13  Present Medium.energy.swimming  9   0.001212121
134 13  Present Travel  24  0.003232323
135 14  Absent  Burst   3   3.68E-05
136 14  Absent  Descending  36  0.000441501
137 14  Absent  High.energy.swimming    325 0.003985774
138 14  Absent  Low.energy.swimming 81091   0.9944935
139 14  Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  17  0.000208487
140 14  Absent  Travel  68  0.000833947
141 14  Present Descending  185 0.00302332
142 14  Present High.energy.swimming    1349    0.022045726
143 14  Present Low.energy.swimming 59269   0.968590152
144 14  Present Medium.energy.swimming  46  0.000751745
145 14  Present Travel  342 0.005589057
146 15  Present Burst   10  0.004938272
147 15  Present Descending  23  0.011358025
148 15  Present High.energy.swimming    1231    0.607901235
149 15  Present Low.energy.swimming 525 0.259259259
150 15  Present Travel  236 0.11654321
151 16  Absent  Ascending   21  0.000618375
152 16  Absent  Burst   11  0.00032391
153 16  Absent  Descending  18  0.000530035
154 16  Absent  High.energy.swimming    323 0.00951119
155 16  Absent  Low.energy.swimming 33210   0.977915194
156 16  Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  66  0.001943463
157 16  Absent  Travel  311 0.009157833
158 16  Present Ascending   128 0.008584842
159 16  Present Descending  143 0.009590879
160 16  Present High.energy.swimming    205 0.013749162
161 16  Present Low.energy.swimming 14321   0.960496311
162 16  Present Medium.energy.swimming  22  0.00147552
163 16  Present Travel  91  0.006103286
164 17  Absent  Ascending   1336    0.010179125
165 17  Absent  Descending  14078   0.10726177
166 17  Absent  High.energy.swimming    26421   0.201304391
167 17  Absent  Low.energy.swimming 82871   0.631402906
168 17  Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  4767    0.036320277
169 17  Absent  Travel  1776    0.013531532
170 17  Present Burst   12  0.004
171 17  Present Descending  121 0.040333333
172 17  Present High.energy.swimming    616 0.205333333
173 17  Present Low.energy.swimming 2050    0.683333333
174 17  Present Medium.energy.swimming  85  0.028333333
175 17  Present Travel  116 0.038666667
176 18  Absent  Ascending   8   0.000142608
177 18  Absent  Descending  15  0.000267389
178 18  Absent  High.energy.swimming    130 0.002317373
179 18  Absent  Low.energy.swimming 55850   0.995579165
180 18  Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  13  0.000231737
181 18  Absent  Travel  82  0.001461728
182 18  Present Descending  78  0.005450734
183 18  Present High.energy.swimming    402 0.028092243
184 18  Present Low.energy.swimming 13472   0.941439553
185 18  Present Medium.energy.swimming  8   0.00055905
186 18  Present Travel  350 0.024458421
187 19  Absent  Burst   94  0.001301254
188 19  Absent  Descending  42  0.000581411
189 19  Absent  High.energy.swimming    24407   0.337869265
190 19  Absent  Low.energy.swimming 15535   0.215053019
191 19  Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  15232   0.210858551
192 19  Absent  Travel  16928   0.234336499
193 19  Present High.energy.swimming    1746    0.404353868
194 19  Present Low.energy.swimming 676 0.15655396
195 19  Present Medium.energy.swimming  284 0.06577119
196 19  Present Travel  1612    0.373320982
197 20  Absent  Ascending   58  0.000410628
198 20  Absent  Burst   3   2.12E-05
199 20  Absent  Descending  172 0.001217725
200 20  Absent  High.energy.swimming    24064   0.17036822
201 20  Absent  Low.energy.swimming 91414   0.647192507
202 20  Absent  Medium.energy.swimming  2747    0.019448201
203 20  Absent  Travel  22789   0.16134148
204 20  Present Descending  41  0.007135399
205 20  Present High.energy.swimming    1612    0.280542986
206 20  Present Low.energy.swimming 2801    0.487469544
207 20  Present Medium.energy.swimming  119 0.020710059
208 20  Present Travel  1173    0.204142012
```

[image: Geom_boxplot - current incorrect output]

This creates one mean point, but I need to have 14 means (one for each behaviour in each absent and present).

Comment: Please can you improve the code. There's a missing parenthesis in `theme()`, `my_scale` is not defined and the y-variable `percentage` is not in the example data.

Comment: Change the main `ggplot` call `aes()` to `aes(x=w.wout, y= percentage, fill=PredictedBehaviour, group = interaction(w.wout,PredictedBehaviour))`. Then add the argument `position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)` to the `stat_summary` call.

Answer (score 1):

The data you posted didn't work so I've used (modified) `iris` dataset.

```
# loading tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

# adding another factor variable to replicate this example
iris$Variable = rep(LETTERS[1:5], times = 30)
```

Here's the meat.

```
iris %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = Variable)) +
   geom_boxplot() +
   stat_summary(fun = mean, color = "steelblue", position = position_dodge(0.75),
                geom = "point", shape = 20, size = 5,
                show.legend = FALSE) +
   theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to add in fun.y to replace the fun=mean as you are currently getting the mean of the whole group instead of each variable.
I think this would work below.

```
ggplot(proportionts, 
       aes(x = w.wout, 
           y = percentage, 
           fill = PredictedBehaviour)) +
geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, 
             geom = "point", 
             shape = 20, 
             size = 3, 
             color = "red", 
             fill = "red") +
theme_classic() + 
my_scale + 
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, 
                                 angle = 0))
```

Comment: Did you try this code? It makes no difference (when edited to address the problems with the original code).